# One bundle for several pages with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have several pages and want to compile all scripts into one bundle.

I know that it is possible to have several entries for each page, but it will generate several bundles for different pages.

Why one bundle so important for me:

- versioning of build is more convenient when the result is one bundle instead of several (like, bundle-1.0.1.js)
- it can be cached once and used in all the pages

Something like this:

```
page1.html
...
<script src="bundle.js" entry-module="module-for-page1"></script>
...

page2.html 
...
<script src="bundle.js" entry-module="module-for-page2"></script>
...
```

Comment: You could write the logic that deals with `entry-module="module-for-page2"`. That module would require all other modules and be the only entry point.

Comment: @FelixKling. Well, I see it like this: build all modules into one bundle, add special startup (entry) module which would search for *entry-module* attr, and *require()* specified module. The problem is, webpack will not bundle all the modules since some of them not referenced from the other. Hm...

Comment: @FelixKling. It turns out that we can conditionally require modules, and they all will be bundled. But all modules should be explicitly specified in require().  So my solution is [this](https://github.com/artin-phares/webpack-entry-module/blob/master/example/src/webpack-entry-module.js)

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main idea of possible workaround:

You set special bootstrap module as entry point when building.
When running, this module extracts name of startup module from script-tag attribute, and conditionally requires it.

---

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
   ...
   entry: "./webpack-entry-module.js",
   ...
}
```

webpack-entry-module.js:

```
var entryModule = document.querySelector('script').getAttribute('webpack-entry-module');

switch(entryModule) {
case 'module1.js': require('./module1.js'); break;
case 'module2.js': require('./module2.js'); break;
}
```

Now you can reference modules from html:

```html
page1.html:
<script src="bundle.js" webpack-entry-module="module1.js"></script>

page2.html:
<script src="bundle.js" webpack-entry-module="module2.js"></script>
```

---

Complete example is here:
https://github.com/artin-phares/webpack-entry-module

Comment: If the link is dead, then your answer becomes useless. Include the code here and explain your solution.